# Adding Recessed Lighting and Switches to Pull Chain Fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, fans

I currently have a ceiling fan with light in my living room.  It has no switch, and is controlled solely by pull chains.  I would like to add recessed lighting to the room, and I would like to add two switches: one for the fan, and a dimmer for the recessed lighting.  What is the simplest way of adding these two switches? A 3 wire switch loop? If so what is the proper wiring configuration.

Comment: So there's no switch for this fan at all? You have to cut power at the breaker? Also, what access do you have above the box and into your walls?

Comment: The only switch is the pull chain.  There is no wall switch.  Sorry for the confusion.

I have attic access above the room.

Comment: Next question: you want two switches total (one fan and one lights) or two switches for the light and one for the fan?

Comment: How is this living room laid out?

Comment: One switch for fan, one switch for recessed lights.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get by running 14-3 wire from the box to a double gang box. Make the white wire your incoming hot, nut it to your two switches, wire switch #1 to the black, and finally switch #2 to the red. You can then attach the lights to your black at the box, and the fan to the red.

NEC recommends dropping a neutral to the box, however. If you can, get some  14/2/2 wire (4 line) and use the blue (or white-red stripe in some) to bring your hot in. Hook the white to the neutral and then nut it off in the switch box.

Comment: "NEC recommends dropping a neutral to the box" this has been _required_ for several years now.